# Storing reference to other class object

Tags: php, object

I come from a java background and m trying a hand at php. Right now I m trying to pass a object to constructor of a class and trying to store a reference to it inside the class and upon a function call to this call execute a method from the stored reference.

```
$phpBook = new Book("Php Book", 500);
$vihaan = new Person("Vihaan", $phpBook);
```

Person.php

```
class Person
{
    private $_book;
    private $_name;

    public function __construct($name, $book)
    {
        $_this->_book = $book;
        $_this->_name = $name;
    }
```

on this line

```
    $_this->_book = $book;
```

I get a warning.

```
PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/vihaan/workspace/AdapterPattern1/Person.php on line 12
```

and this function call never enter the if block as $_book seems to be empty.

```
public function openBook($pageNumber = 0)
{
    if(!empty($_book))
    {
        $_book->open($pageNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `$this`, not `$_this`!

```
$this->_book = $book;
$this->_name = $name;
```